# When I use sharedPreferences in Flutter ,the console reported bugs like this repeatedly?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:64672/dart_sdk.js:5348:11)
    at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:64672/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:962:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:64672/dart_sdk.js:39230:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:64672/dart_sdk.js:39087:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:64672/dart_sdk.js:34073:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:64672/dart_sdk.js:34633:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:64672/dart_sdk.js:34671:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:64672/dart_sdk.js:34513:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:64672/dart_sdk.js:34536:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:64672/dart_sdk.js:39374:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:64672/dart_sdk.js:39380:13)
    at http://localhost:64672/dart_sdk.js:34887:9
```

But my program can run smoothly and the used `sharedpreferences` works well too .I think the multiple occurence can be attributed to my several use of sharedPreferences.
Does the version of shared_preference dependency devote to this bug?
My version is:
`shared_preferences: ^0.4.2`
Can anyone solve this,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the earlier versions you can initial manually [Doc](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/versions/0.4.2):

```
const MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences')
  .setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
    if (methodCall.method == 'getAll') {
      return <String, dynamic>{}; // set initial values here if desired
    }
    return null;
  });
```

Comment: Could you tell me where can I insert this code? In main?Thank you

Comment: I use a higher version     shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+8   ,it runs ok